# Update azure devops release pipeline: Tasks with versions 'Deploy Plataform 3:1.*' are not valid for deploy job 'Run on agent'

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using Azure DevOps Services REST API 5.0 to update a pipeline release.

I have a release with a stage DEV that have two tasks in a 'Run on agent' job:

- Deploy plataform 1
- Deploy plataform 2

I want to add a new task 'Deploy plataform 3' using the [update method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) from the Azure DevOps Services REST API.

But when I try to UPDATE have the error:
**Tasks with versions 'Deploy Plataform 3:1.*' are not valid for deploy job 'Run on agent' in stage DEV.**

I [get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) the release definition using the url:
`https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/organizationname/projectname/_apis/release/definitions/5?api-version=5.0`

I add a new task in the object `environments[0].deployPhases[0].workflowTasks`.

`Workflowtasks` object with my new task:

```
"workflowTasks": [
    {
        "environment": {},
        "taskId": "501dd25d-1785-43e4-b4e5-a5c78ccc0573",
        "version": "1.*",
        "name": "Deploy Plataform 1",
        "refName": "",
        "enabled": true,
        "alwaysRun": false,
        "continueOnError": false,
        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
        "definitionType": null,
        "overrideInputs": {},
        "condition": "succeeded()",
        "inputs": {
            "azureSubscription": "3ca9b800-e82b-4678-8483-xxxxx",
            "appType": "$(Parameters.AppType)",
            "appName": "app func name 1",
            "deployToSlotOrASE": "false",
            "resourceGroupName": "",
            "slotName": "production",
            "package": "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip",
            "runtimeStack": "",
            "startUpCommand": "",
            "customWebConfig": "",
            "appSettings": "",
            "configurationStrings": "",
            "deploymentMethod": "auto"
        }
    },
    { ...
    },
    {
        "environment": {},
        "taskId": "502dd25d-1785-43e4-b4e5-a5c78ccc0573",
        "version": "1.*",
        "name": "Deploy Plataform 3",
        "refName": "",
        "enabled": true,
        "alwaysRun": false,
        "continueOnError": false,
        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
        "definitionType": "task",
        "overrideInputs": {},
        "condition": "succeeded()",
        "inputs": {
            "azureSubscription": "3ca9b844-e92b-4678-8483-xxxx",
            "appType": "functionApp",
            "appName": "func app name",
            "deployToSlotOrASE": "false",
            "resourceGroupName": "",
            "slotName": "production",
            "package": "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip",
            "runtimeStack": "",
            "startUpCommand": "",
            "customWebConfig": "",
            "appSettings": "",
            "configurationStrings": "",
            "deploymentMethod": "auto"
        }
    }
]
```

PUT url: `https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=5.0`

**Error:**

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Tasks with versions 'Deploy Plataform 3:1.*' are not valid for deploy job 'Run on agent' in stage DEV.
","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Data.Exceptions.InvalidRequestException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement2.Data","typeKey":"InvalidRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
Au caractère C:\Projects\TransportConfiguration\AutomationTasks\Build Definitions Supporting Scripts\Update-Release-Stage.ps1:49 : 9
+         Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers ($Header) -Method PUT -B ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Put method:

```
function Invoke-WebRequestPut ([PSCustomObject] $releaseDefinition) {    

    $uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/organizationname/projectname/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=5.0"

    $Auth = '{0}:{1}' -f $UserName, $PersonalToken
    $Auth = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Auth)
    $Auth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Auth)
    $Header = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $Auth)} 

    $body = $releaseDefinition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 30

    $body2 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body)


    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers ($Header) -Method PUT -Body $body2 -ContentType "application/json"
}
```

Using this put method I can modify an existing task name successfully (Deploy Plataform 1 => Deploy Plataform X). But can not add a new task.

This is a bug or I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you try add another tasks? change the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.
The new `WorkflowTask` I add has a field `taskId` that I was trying to generate. But this `taskId` field corresponds to the *azure pipeline task* type I want to use. In my case, I need to set the *azure function app* task id, `501dd25d-1785-43e4-b4e5-a5c78ccc0573`.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#workflowtask) for WorkflowTask is not complete, we only have: `TaskId: string`